# Short IF and Long IF Variable Assignment Method in PHP

Tags: php

I have 2 codes that do the same task. 2.In the long code `$sort = 'newest';` I'm throwing the variable. But in the 1st shortcode I don't know how to assign it.

**The code to be edited is the 1st Code. (Short Code)*

**Short IF PHP Code**

```
$sql_code_orderby = ( $sort == 'oldest' ? "ORDER BY Q.created ASC" : ($sort == 'votes' || ($sort == '' && $filter == 'noanswers')) ? "ORDER BY Q.vote_count DESC" : ($sort == 'viewed' ? "ORDER BY Q.viewed DESC" : "ORDER BY Q.created DESC" ) );
```

**Long IF PHP Code**

```
if( $sort == 'oldest' ){
    $sql_code_orderby = "ORDER BY Q.created ASC";
} else if( $sort == 'votes' || ($sort == '' && $filter == 'noanswers')  ){
    $sql_code_orderby = "ORDER BY Q.vote_count DESC";
} else if( $sort == 'viewed' ){
    $sql_code_orderby = "ORDER BY Q.viewed DESC";
} else {
    $sort = 'newest';
    $sql_code_orderby = "ORDER BY Q.created DESC";
}
```

**My fault trial result:**

```
$sql_code_orderby = ( $sort == 'oldest' ? "ORDER BY Q.created ASC" : ($sort == 'votes' || ($sort == '' && $filter == 'noanswers')) ? "ORDER BY Q.vote_count DESC" : ($sort == 'viewed' ? "ORDER BY Q.viewed DESC" : "ORDER BY Q.created DESC" .  ($sort = 'newest') ) );
```

Comment: The short version is called a "conditional (or ternary) expression".

Comment: Also, nested ternary expressions like that are generally considered bad practice as they are difficult to read and reason about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using nested ternary expressions like the "short code" are generally considered bad practice as they are difficult to read, understand, and maintain. In a team environment, I would expect any code that uses them to be rejected in code review.

In a case like this, I'd probably use a [switch statement](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php) something like the below:

```
$direction = 'DESC';

switch (true) {
    case $sort === 'oldest':
        $column = "created";
        $direction = 'ASC';
        break;
    case $sort === 'votes':
    case $sort === '' && $filter === 'noanswers':
        $column = "vote_count";
        break;
    case $sort === 'viewed':
        $column = "viewed";
        break;
    default:
        $column = "created";
        break;
}

$sql_code_orderby = "ORDER BY Q.$column $direction";
```

Comment: This is in my humble opinion not what the OP asked.

Comment: @MaxMuster I agree and would submit that the OP has asked an X vs Y question. ie, they asked "How do I assign this variable based on various input in one single line?" when they really need to know "How can I better assign this variable based on various input?" Wanting to do this on one line is an arbitrary and meaningless restriction.

Answer (score 0):

With another condition ?

```php
$sql_code_orderby = ( 
    $sort == 'oldest' ? "ORDER BY Q.created ASC" : 
        ($sort == 'votes' || ($sort == '' && $filter == 'noanswers')) ? "ORDER BY Q.vote_count DESC" : 
            ($sort == 'viewed' ? "ORDER BY Q.viewed DESC" : "ORDER BY Q.created DESC"));
    
if ( $sort!='oldest' && $sort!='votes' && $sort!='viewed' && ($sort=='' && $filter!='noanswers') ){$sort = 'newest';}
```

To explain a little bit: the ternary expression is used to assign a variable. It has the syntax:

```
( **variable condition** ? **variable value for true** : **variable value for false**)
```

So this is why you cannot assign two variables in a ternary if

Comment: While this may work, it's very difficult to read and would be considered bad practice.

Comment: Yes, it is difficult to read, but I thought the OP wanted a short solution to learn about ternary if

Comment: Understandable, and based on that, perhaps we should teach the OP that using nested ternaries is bad practice and this is why.

Comment: it is not bad practice. stop telling this. almost all languages implement it . if it would be bad practice they would not implement it.

Comment: @MaxMuster You solved the problem as I guessed. But I chose the long method because of the comments. Thank you very much for your interest.

Comment: @MaxMuster "if it would be bad practice they would not implement it" - Hello there, do you have a moment to talk about JavaScript ?

Comment: @SteveChamaillard it is also implemented in JavaScript, and maybe it is hard to read if formatting is bad, but if you write pretty code it is not hard to read.

Comment: Sorry Max, I was unclear. Using ternary expressions is not bad practice. Nesting ternary expressions is bad practice. Once we nest a ternary expression inside another ternary expression the code becomes difficult to read, understand, and maintain. The more deeply they are nested, the more exponentially difficult those issues become. I hope that makes more sense.

Comment: yes but all of us who work in this business have a very strong autistic component and are minimalists by nature ;-)

Comment: For what its worth, I disagree. While we all can appreciate a little code golf, in my experience, professional developers prefer to write and read code with clear and concise  intention that is self documenting. The above makes sense to you because you just wrote it and have all the needed context to understand it. A year from now when a Jr developer joins the team and is asked to modify this code, the intention of the code wont be nearly as clear even if formatted a well as possible. In fact, I'd believe even "future you" after a year would need more time to reason out the logic than a switch

Comment: Also, consider debugging. A switch can be easily debugged with breakpoints using xdebug and a good IDE. A nested ternary would not allow breakpoints to be used at all.

Comment: @MaxMuster I’d like to point out that the argument that says “if it was bad practice, they wouldn’t implement it” is unfortunately false, seeing what crazy stuff JavaScript has implemented.

Comment: Not to pile on, but note that the assertion "you cannot assign two variables in a ternary if" is also false. You can actually assign any number of variables you'd like in a ternary statement, you just have to apply the proper parentheses  [as can be seen in this example](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e6f52bee7fbcb110191db9698f98f97677705081) *NOTE* the example here is NOT an endorsement, actually using something like this would of course be even worse practice.

Comment: @WesleySmith he is assigning `$sql_code_orderby`. One variable. In this way how OP asked the question it is not possible to assign another variable in something like `$sql_code_orderby=( if ? thenValue : elseValue);` nested or not it is not possible.

Comment: Sure it is, `$someCodition ? $sql_code_orderby = 'some value' : $sql_code_orderby = 'some other value';`, and you could do it with as many nested values you wanted, even setting intermittent variables along the way to be used in the nests. It would just be really hard to read but you dont have to have an = at the start to do assignment in a ternary.

Comment: @WesleySmith you are denaturing the OP' question again. He asked how to assign a second variable in a nested assignment of a variable: ` $sql_code_orderby=( if ? thenValue : elseValue); `  and he did not want to use a simple ternary like ` if ? thenValue : elseValue ` He was able to correctly nested it 3 times.  And the correct answer is it works only with a second if statement. And I wish you a wonderful Sunday !

Comment: Im sorry you see it that way.